# How do I set the PHP version for a contrib module with GitLab CI?

Tags: testing

I'm trying to set up testing using the [GitLab template for contrib modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/gitlab_templates).

In the module's `composer.json`, PHP 8.2 is required, and since the CI is currently defaulting to 8.1, the install fails.

So, based on the [variables documentation](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/gitlab_templates/-/blob/main/includes/include.drupalci.variables.yml), I tried adding the following to `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  _TARGET_PHP: "8.3"
```

When I pushed and the pipeline ran, it was still at PHP 8.1.

So then I tried:

```
variables:
  _TARGET_PHP: "CORE_PHP_MAX"
```

Which according to the docs linked above is currently 8.3.

However, that failed too-- still stuck at 8.1.

How do I set the PHP version for GitLab CI for a contrib module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
variables:
  CORE_PHP_MIN: "8.2"
```

You can use `_TARGET_PHP: "8.3"` on a job like composer and PHPUnit. There are a few ways you can do this. Which project are you working on? I want to look at your pipeline.

Comment: Pipelines here: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/decoupled_passkeys/-/pipelines.  Both `CORE_PHP_MIN` and `_TARGET_PHP` work; the reason I didn't think they were working is because I had `TARGET_PHP` instead of `_TARGET_PHP` in the file.  D'oh!  Too bad there is no linting error for this kind of mistake.